# How to unlock admin in magento 1.9.3.3 using database?

Tags: magento-1.9.3.3

After entering the wrong password Magento has locked my admin account, How can I unlock this using database?

If there is another way of unlocking admin account please tell me. My Magento version is 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the SQL way of unlocking a Magento admin account:

```
UPDATE admin_user 
SET failures_num=0, first_failure=NULL, lock_expires=NULL
WHERE username='<username>';
```

Replace the `<username>` with the target account's username.

Answer (score 7):

Select the corresponding database from the drop down menu on the left side.

After that click on the SQL tab in order to be able to execute the following MySQL query and use the following code to unlock your admin account using database:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = md5('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD'), is_active = 1 WHERE `username` = 'YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME';
```

Or you can create a new admin account. Just add this code in admin.php file and put the file on your magento root folder. After this just access this file `www.example.com/admin.php`
Your new

```
username: magento
password: magento1234
```

---

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);

Mage::app(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());//if you changed the code for the default store view change it here also
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$username = 'magento';//desired username
$firstname = "Magento";//desired firstname
$lastname = "Developer";//desired lastname
$email = "magento@example.com";//desired email
$pass = 'magento1234';//desired password
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($username, 'username');
if ($user->getId()){
 echo "User {$username} already exists";
 exit;
}

$user->setUsername($username)
  ->setFirstname($firstname)
  ->setLastname($lastname)
  ->setEmail($email)
  ->setPassword($pass)
  ;

$result = $user->validate();
if (is_array($result)){
 foreach ($result as $res){
  echo $res."\n";
 }
 exit;
}

try{
 $user->setForceNewPassword(true);
 $user->save();
 $user->setRoleIds(array(1))->saveRelations();
 echo "User {$username} was created";
 exit;
}

catch (Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [N98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) , you should simply execute this command:

```
../n98-magerun.phar admin:user:unlock {admin_username}
```

Answer (score 0):

very very simple

just go `PhpMyAdmin`

find `admin_user`

click `edit`

password section add your `password` and select `md5` on right side

click **GO** button

DONE!

if this helpful please thumpsUp.
[image]